# Color ramp in multiple attributes symbology (Arcmap)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, symbology

I am trying to use the "multiple attributes" symbology tool in Arcmap 10.

I would like to divide my data in 2 categories. For each categories, I would like to display a color ramp.

I read ESRI's documentation about that, but I can't figure how to obtain the proper color ramp:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdtvE.png)

I want to have a "green" color ramp for the first category (value '0'), and a "red" color ramp for the second one (value '1').

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think Multiple Attributes is designed to work like that - have you tried just using Quantities>Graduated Colors on one field and then doing a Copy/Paste Layer(s) of that layer to create a second one for which you change the field and color ramp used?

Comment: Your solution is a possibility, but if I need to workd with two layers, How can I 'exclude' all the records belonging to category '1' in the first layer (and conversly in the second layer) in order to display the two color ramps at the same time? I precise that my two categories are built to never overlap

Comment: For that set a Definition Query (tab on layer Properties) on each of the layers.  Once you have that working you may want to think about creating a Layer Group from the two layers so that you can turn it off/on with a single click.

Comment: Excellent!  I've now transferred my Comments to an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Attributes is not designed to work like that so instead:

1. Use **Quantities>Graduated Colors** on one field and then do a **Copy**/**Paste Layer(s)** of that layer to create a second one for which you can change the field and color ramp used.
2. To exclude complementary features from the two layers set a **Definition Query** (tab on layer Properties) on each of the layers.
3. You may also want to think about creating a **Layer Group** from the two layers so that you can turn it off/on with a single click.